# Installing USB drivers

Tags: usb, mojave, headphones, driver

Is there a way to force macOS to reinstall a set of USB drivers for a device?

I have a pair of headphones from Sennheiser that are no longer recognised, i.e. not shown as an output device in the Sound Preferences.

Comment: Are these third-party drivers? Just run the installer. Are the headphones listed as an output device in System Preferences, or not? If so, what happens when you select them? What Mac model is this? What version of MacOs?

Comment: The drivers automatically installed the first time I connected the headphones. They are not listed as an output device. Turned out it was a faulty USB cable. Still, I'd like to know the answer for future reference. macOS 10.14.5 Mojave, MacBook Pro, Late 2013.

Comment: I'm confused. These are USB headphones, and when you plugged them in, they didn't show up as Output devices (because of a defective intermediary cable), but drivers from somewhere started downloading and installing? Most USB audio devices work without drivers - you just plug them in and the system recognises them. There's no mechanism for third-party drivers to be instantly installed when you plug something in. Can you describe exactly what happened? Was this through System Updates or Mac App Store, or some other way?

Comment: Sure. A long time ago, I connected the headphones via USB. At that time, there was a prompt for a download; IIRC I believe it was drivers. The only other similar behaviour I can think of is when you try to connect a printer for the first time. It was either macOS Sierra or High Sierra at the time. Didn't have to go through the Mac App Store or the Software Update mechanism.

Comment: It's probably best to look on the Sennheiser website for updates to their USB drivers for Mac.

Comment: I already have. There doesn't appear to be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers and firmware get updated as part of OS installation and all OS installations now are archive and install which means the OS builds up a clean OS with all the drivers needed, patches firmware and then runs the migration script to move in any custom drivers you have.

That's a great first step if you ever feel your firmware or drivers are not up to snuff.

If you don't have a caching server locally - then download the OS installer from the Mac App Store then run the installer over lunch or when you're done for the evening. You can also boot to recovery or internet recovery on newer Macs and reinstall.

Caching server will cache the installer, so you might be done with the download at LAN speeds (6 minutes or less) and the install takes maybe 10 minutes for the part everyone has to run. Your migration could take 1 minute to 30 minutes based on how many software and extensions you have.

Comment: Won't that just replace the same old third-party drivers? It's not going to update them is it?

Comment: This covers a failed install, out of date drivers, known bad drivers that are disabled when Apple checks. So no, it doesn’t necessarily just replace them but it could just replace them. You’d have to track all the files and specifics to know @benwiggy